# Extension of a continuous function from a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:D(\subseteq\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function where $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then is it true that there always exists an extension of $f$ which is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

I have tried to consider several examples and it seems that such an extension always exists. But I cannot prove it. How can I prove this (if it can be proved at all)?

Comment: $D = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\; f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Make it uniformly continuous.

Comment: If you want to extend a function on $f:D\to\Bbb R$ continuously to $\Bbb R$, I believe the condition would be: _$f$ is uniformly continuous on every set of the form $[-N,N]\cap D$._ As @Daniel's and my examples show, simply assuming $f$ is continuous is not enough.

Comment: In fact $f$ can be so extended iff $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-r,r)$ for every $r>0.$

Comment: @zhw. That's interesting, could you refer me to a proof?

Comment: @zhw. Edit: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this should do it- if $f$ has a continuous extension $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[-r, r]$, and then so is $f$. Conversely, if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-r, r)$ it has a continuous extension on this interval. As this is true for all $r > 0$, it has a continuous extension on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$, defined by:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<\sqrt2\\1,&x>\sqrt2\end{cases}$$
Note that I didn't need to define $f(\sqrt2)$, as $\sqrt2$ is not in the domain.

A function is called *continuous* if it's continuous at every point $x$ in its domain. So, technically, $f$ is continuous. You want to say it's discontinuous at $\sqrt2$, but $f$ would stare at you blankly and ask, "What's $\sqrt2$?"

Of course, you can't continuously extend this to $\Bbb R$.